# In Javascript, can I put an OnTrigger function within an Update function?

Tags: unityscript, unity-game-engine

I am trying to build a game and I need to make the player get the key then the fountain (don't ask)
I am not familiar with javascript or c# but i tried to piecemeal it together:

on key:
    `#pragma strict
    var scoreKeeper : GameObject;
    function OnTriggerEnter () {
    scoreKeeper.SendMessage("UpdateScore",SendMessageOptions.DontRequireReceiver);
    }`

on fountain

```
#pragma strict
function UpdateScore {
    function OnTriggerEnter(other : Collider){

    Application.LoadLevel(2);

    }
}
```

So how do I get this to work?
FYI I am familiar with code but not object oriented languages

Answer (score 0):

have a bool (fe. hasKey) on your fountain which is set to true once the player aquired the key?
or have the fountain check wheter or not the player has the key in his inventory.

personally id probably go the 2nd road since its easier to expand on and all values are neatly packed into the player(s inventory).

also api says send message only works on the same gameobject (never used it myself ^^), you sure this is what you want?
http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.SendMessage.html